# Straighten largest line in image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have a large number of images of food items on a trey, the tray is the largest thing in the picture and it always contains the largest line. i.e.
[image: Input image]
*I had to Photoshop out the items on the trey*

i want a script that can align and straighten the trey, like so:
[image: expected output]

Is this possible using python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach

- Convert image to grayscale
- Otsu's threshold to get a binary image
- Find contours and filter using approximate contour
- Perspective transform for top-down view
- Rotate image to get correct orientation

---

After converting to grayscale, we Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image

[image]

Now we find contours on this image and filter using `cv2.arcLength()` and `cv2.approxPolyDP()`. The idea is that if the contour has approximately 4 corners, then it must be our desired object. Additional filtering steps could be to use `cv2.contourArea()` to ensure that only the largest contour is used. Here's the detected contour

[image]

From here we perform a perspective transform to get a top-down view

[image]

Finally we rotate the image depending on the desired orientation. Here's the result

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

def perspective_transform(image, corners):
    def order_corner_points(corners):
        # Separate corners into individual points
        # Index 0 - top-right
        #       1 - top-left
        #       2 - bottom-left
        #       3 - bottom-right
        corners = [(corner[0][0], corner[0][1]) for corner in corners]
        top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r = corners[0], corners[1], corners[2], corners[3]
        return (top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l)

    # Order points in clockwise order
    ordered_corners = order_corner_points(corners)
    top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l = ordered_corners

    # Determine width of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (bottom right and bottom left) or (top right and top left) x-coordinates
    width_A = np.sqrt(((bottom_r[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((bottom_r[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    width_B = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - top_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - top_l[1]) ** 2))
    width = max(int(width_A), int(width_B))

    # Determine height of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (top right and bottom right) or (top left and bottom left) y-coordinates
    height_A = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - bottom_r[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - bottom_r[1]) ** 2))
    height_B = np.sqrt(((top_l[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_l[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    height = max(int(height_A), int(height_B))

    # Construct new points to obtain top-down view of image in 
    # top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r order
    dimensions = np.array([[0, 0], [width - 1, 0], [width - 1, height - 1], 
                    [0, height - 1]], dtype = "float32")

    # Convert to Numpy format
    ordered_corners = np.array(ordered_corners, dtype="float32")

    # Find perspective transform matrix
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(ordered_corners, dimensions)

    # Return the transformed image
    return cv2.warpPerspective(image, matrix, (width, height))

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.015 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        cv2.drawContours(image,[c], 0, (36,255,12), 3)
        transformed = perspective_transform(original, approx)

rotated = imutils.rotate_bound(transformed, angle=-90)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('transformed', transformed)
cv2.imshow('rotated', rotated)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks. I also had to use ```cv2.getStructuringElement``` and ```cv2.dilate``` to the threshold image before finding contours as i realized some of my trey images had protruding objects on the trey.